# Artifactory - how to validate new proxy url connections for remote repositories

Tags: maven, proxy, artifactory

How to validate if Artifactory can connect to Remote repository via Proxy url configured under proxies.

The situation came up when the enterprise Proxy url changed from old.proxy.com to new.proxy.com

I made the change but after that maven is unable to obtain the artifacts from Maven central.

Please help..

Answer (score 3):

When configuring a [remote repository](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Remote+Repositories) in Artifactory you have a "Test" button which allows you to check whether Artifactory can access the remote repository. You can use this to check if you are able to access the remote repository using your new proxy definitions.

Comment: Thanks for the link @drorb . Unfortunately I am using version 2.2.4 which I know is like a stone age version considering the latest upgrades :( .. Its hard for me to get the version updated. Any other option to get the Testing done in older versions ??

Comment: I do not think you have an option to test it in 2.2.4 besides actually trying to use the repository